# How to remove count after grouping in angular UI grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

After grouping a column in the UI grid, count of no. of records in that category is displayed next to it, how can I remove it as shown in the below image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to find in [the documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.grouping.api:GridOptions), but you can hide these by setting the `groupingShowCounts` property of the grid options to `false`.

eg.

`<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-grouping class="grid"></div>`

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: $scope.data,
    groupingShowCounts: false
};
```

Answer (score 1):

ref - [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/), In AG grid 23.x.x, this can be solved by  autoGroupColumnDef.cellRendererParams.suppressCount = true